Discrepancies in Evaluation Metrics for Identical Outputs in Azure AI Studio Using GPT-3.5-Turbo Prompt Flows
I have a question about evaluation metrics for question-answering with context using GPT-3.5-turbo in Prompt Flow. I created two prompt flows to generate model answers and assess performance metrics. Both flows have identical structures, with the only difference being the deployment name.
Prompt Flow Structure
I fine-tuned two different model deployments from the same base model (gpt-3.5-turbo-0125) using identical settings but different training datasets. For evaluation, I used the same test set across both prompt flows and deployment names.
Evaluation Flow
After the evaluation, the generated answers were identical between the two models without any space or special characters, and all inputs like question, context, and ground truth are the same as both evaluation pipelines use the same file. However, the metrics like coherence, fluency, groundedness, similarity, and relevance showed significant differences.
Output Metric from first model
Output Metric from second model
According to the documentation, these metrics don't require a model as input. For example, Relevance only requires question, context, and model's answer.
Azure AI Studio Documentation
Could you help me identify if I might have missed something or why the model seems to impact the metric calculation even all the inputs are identical?

Most of these metrics use GPT to evaluate. Look inside of these metrics source code - it's literally just asking GPT model "Please evaluate this and that and give it a score between 1 and 5."
That means that these evaluators have random seed and they can return different value every time you run them. Even if the input data is exactly the same. Just like a ChatGPT returns different answer every time you ask the same question.
You just need to change your mentality. You shouldn't think of the score like a deterministic result of some classic algorithm designed by a math professor from Harvard. It's closer to sending a big Excel file to a low-paid intern and telling him to type in a score in the last column.
These scores aren't intended to be analyzed in separation. You are supposed to run hundreds of different question-answer pairs and draw a chart or calculate average. After you do that, these discrepancies will be statistically insignificant.
